# Managing a new page in tcpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm generating pdf reports in php using tcpdf. The first page positions all textbox correctly down the page, but textboxes in subsequent pages are placed in the header(One textbox per page) making my document so long.

```
//code 
 require_once('../report/header.php');
 // add a page
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $p=30;
 for ($i = 30; $i < 1000; $i = $i + 20) {    
  $pdf->CreateTextBox('PATIENT CARD' . $i, 30, $p, 120, 40, 20);
  $p=$p+20;
 }
```

I have made a solution that detects if I have reached the bottom of a page to try and fix the above but its not usable incase of dynamic text(where you get text from the database). The solution adds a new page in case I have reached a certain value in y axis and resets the y axis

```
//code
 require_once('../report/header.php');
 // add a page
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $p=30;
 for ($i = 30; $i < 1000; $i = $i + 20) { 
  $pdf->CreateTextBox('PATIENT CARD' . $i, 30, $p, 120, 40, 20);
  if ($i == 230 || $i == 430 || $i==......){
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $p=30;        
   }
  $p=$p+20;
 }
```

Is there a way that the new pages can be added automatically and the value of y axis reset for the new page?